# Unable to move mails to sent folder of IMAP using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, smtp, imap

I am sending emails from my laravel website using SMTP. When i send email to the user then i want to copy that mail to IMAP sent folder too.
Here is my code when i am sending mail to user:

```
        $mail = Mail::to($this->receiver)
            ->send(new ComplaintMail($this->sender->user_email,$this->subject,$this->complaint,$this->answers,$this->sender));

        $path = "{mypath.com:993/imap/ssl}Sent";
        $imapStream = imap_open($path,$this->sender->user_email,$this->sender->email_password);
        $result = imap_append($imapStream,$path,$mail->getSentMIMEMessage());
        imap_close($imapStream);
```

Also I tried using imap_mail_move() method like so:

```
        $mail = Mail::to($this->receiver)
            ->send(new ComplaintMail($this->sender->user_email,$this->subject,$this->complaint,$this->answers,$this->sender));

        $path = "{mypath.com:993/imap/ssl}Sent";
        $imapStream = imap_open($path,$this->sender->user_email,$this->sender->email_password);
        imap_mail_move($imapStream,$mail,$path);
        imap_close($imapStream);
```

Both ways it didn't worked out

In ComplaintMail class, build function looks like :

```
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->from($this->sender)
                    ->subject($this->subject)
                    ->markdown('emails.complaint');
    }
```

Comment: Doesn't work how?  imap_append is what you want; imap_mail_move can only move from IMAP, not SMTP.

Comment: My Sent folder is still empty when i try to get the sent emails by using Laravel IMAP

Comment: I found the problem, in above code Mail::from()->send() , returns null. So $mail variable is null. But i don't know how to fix this

Comment: Just do $mail = new ComplaintMail....  then do the send, then do the append.  Break it into a separate step.